# Android Studio : display date got from another activity

Tags: android, date, android-activity

In an activity, I ask my user about a date using a datepicker.
As far as I found, the best way to pass this date to a subsequent activity is to send separately yea, month and day.

In my subsequent activity, I want to display this date, but also this date+ 1 day, + 2 days and so on.

To do it, I taught I can do :

```
int mDay = origine.getIntExtra("mDay", 0);
int mMonth= origine.getIntExtra("mMonth", 0);
int mYear = origine.getIntExtra("mYear", 0);
calendrier = new GregorianCalendar(mYear,mMonth,mDay);
```

and then put it in a string using something like

```
String strcal01 = sdf.format(new calendrier);
```

This line don't work but it works if I replace "calendrier" by "Date()" (of course with current date and not the date get from the other activity...

What can I do to make it working ?

Thank's a lot for your help.

Comment: what is "calendrier" class for? it is Calendar?

Comment: you already have date but you need to display in other activity. right ?

Comment: Calendrier is a variable that I declared as Calendar type.

The date I have here comes from another activity. I don't want to declare it here because the same date can be used in three different activities.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for getting date input from user

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dateValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(DailySalesView.this, datePicker, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
```

Put this inside Activity class

```
String date;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);


String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
        date= sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
            }

        };
```

By this way you'll get formatted date in the `String date`
You can then pass it to another `Activity` with `Intent`.
If you need clarification, feel free to ask!
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `calendrier.getTime()` instead of `new calendrier`

Your mistake:

The method `format` is expecting an object of the type `Date`, You are trying to pass the type `Calendar`. Also FYI, you have used the `new` keyword wrongly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "using the new keyword wrong". I'm sorry by making something wrong and if you could explain me what I made as mistake, I'll try to make better next time.

Comment: `new` is used to create new objects. Correct usage: `new ClassName()`. You are using it as `new objectName`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm correct by answering to my own question but, thank you Joshua.

I finally, in my "guest" activity, create a calendar named calendrier and display the values using :

```
calendrier = new GregorianCalendar(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

cal01=calendrier;
String strcal01 = sdf.format(cal01.getTime());
cal02=calendrier;
cal02.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
String strcal02 = sdf.format(cal02.getTime());
```

I think i can be simplified because fore each date, I have 3 lines. But the most important for me now is that it works !